# Optimize boolean condition in IF statements

Tags: if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I have the following conditions :

```
if (a && (b || c)) {
 await t1();
}
if(b) {
  await t2();
 }
```

Considering t2 should be done AFTER t1, is there a way to optimize those conditions ?

Comment: You realise that if a = false and b=true, t2 will be done and t1 won't?  Just checking because you said t2 should be done after t1, just not sure if you meant only after t1.

Comment: Exact. It is not mandatory to have t1 or t2 executed, but if t1 and t2 are executed, T1 must be finished before t2 start

Comment: Optimise them how? What should be improved here?

Comment: In that case, assuming a,b, and c are variables I wouldn't worry about optimizing for speed.  The difference between the best and worst case will be nanoseconds, and dwarfed by the time of t1 and t2.  Optimize for readability-  which way is easiest to understand for someone with knowledge of the product.

Answer (score 1):

If `b` is likely to be `true`, the following may be a tiny bit faster, but I would probably keep it as you have it.

```
if (b)
{
  if (a)
    await t1();
  await t2();
}
else
{
  if (a && c)
    await t1();
}
```